# Set Custom KeyEquivalent in Services Menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

OmniFocus has a Cocoa Service that allows you to create tasks based upon selected items.

It has a preference that allows you to set the keyboard shortcut that triggers the Service. This is not just a global hotkey, it's a bona fide Service that shows up in the menu.

You can the keyboard shortcut to pretty much any combination, including combinations with ⌥ and ^. This functionality is not documented - the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/Articles/properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000852-CHDJDFIC) seem to say that KeyEquivalents must be a `⌘+[⇧]+someKey`.

Once this is set, I observe three things:

1. The OmniFocus Info.plist file does not contain a KeyEquivalent listed. This is not surprising, as the file is read-only.
2. The pbs -dump_pboard utility lists `NSKeyEquivalent = {};` for the service.
3. Using NSDebugServices lists this interesting line that does not show up with most debugging sessions (Obviously, for keyboard shortcut `⌃⌥⌘M`): `OmniFocus: Send to Inbox (com.omnigroup.OmniFocus) has a custom key equivalent: <NSKeyboardShortcut: 0x7fb18a0d18f0 (⌃⌥⌘M)>.`

So my questions are twofold, and I suspect they are related:

1. How do you dynamically change a service's KeyEquivalent?
2. How do you set the KeyEquivalent to a combination including ⌃ and ⌥

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The basic process is described here: [Register NSService with Command Alt NSKeyEquivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845070/register-nsservice-with-command-alt-nskeyequivalent)

The code is this:

```
//Bundle identifier from Info.plist
NSString* bundleIdentifier = @"com.whatever.MyApp";
//Services -> Menu -> Menu item title from Info.plist
NSString* appServiceName = @"Launch My Service";
//Services -> Instance method name from Info.plist
NSString* methodNameForService = @"myServiceMethod";

//The key equivalent
NSString* keyEquivalent = @"@~r";

CFStringRef serviceStatusName = (CFStringRef)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ - %@", bundleIdentifier, appServiceName, methodNameForService];
CFStringRef serviceStatusRoot =  CFSTR("NSServicesStatus");
CFPropertyListRef pbsAllServices = (CFPropertyListRef) CFMakeCollectable ( CFPreferencesCopyAppValue(serviceStatusRoot, CFSTR("pbs")) );
// the user did not configure any custom services
BOOL otherServicesDefined = pbsAllServices != NULL;
BOOL ourServiceDefined = NO;
if ( otherServicesDefined ) {
    ourServiceDefined = NULL != CFDictionaryGetValue((CFDictionaryRef)pbsAllServices, serviceStatusName);
}

NSUpdateDynamicServices();
NSMutableDictionary *pbsAllServicesNew = nil;
if (otherServicesDefined) {
    pbsAllServicesNew = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)pbsAllServices];
} else {
   pbsAllServicesNew = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
}

NSDictionary *serviceStatus = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               (id)kCFBooleanTrue, @"enabled_context_menu", 
                               (id)kCFBooleanTrue, @"enabled_services_menu", 
                               keyEquivalent, @"key_equivalent", nil];
[pbsAllServicesNew setObject:serviceStatus forKey:(NSString*)serviceStatusName];
CFPreferencesSetAppValue (
                          serviceStatusRoot,
                          (CFPropertyListRef) pbsAllServicesNew,
                          CFSTR("pbs"));
Boolean result = CFPreferencesAppSynchronize(CFSTR("pbs"));
if (result) {
    NSUpdateDynamicServices();
    NSLog(@"successfully installed our alt-command-r service");
} else {
    NSLog(@"couldn't install our alt-command-r service");
}
```

If the code succeeds, you can view this in `~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist`

You should see something like:

```
NSServicesStatus = {
    "com.whatever.MyApp - Launch My Service - myServiceMethod" = {
        enabled_context_menu = :true;
        enabled_services_menu = :true;
        key_equivalent = "@~r";
    };
```